# Iterating over list to add text values to Python ElementTree

Tags: python, loops, elementtree

I seem to be having a syntax problem in Python...

OV: I'm receiving CSV input as a tuple that I want to add as text inside ElementTree elements.  Upon the first iteration of the loop, the data values (starting at [0]) should be added to the elements.  Incrementing to the next data point in the list for each iteration and building new elements.

Here is code block so far:

```
for r in results:
    for key, value in r.iteritems():
       if key == "foo":
           listing = value.split(',')

           type = ET.SubElement(root, "TYPE")
           type.text = +listing[0]+

           value = ET.SubElement(type, "Value")
           value.text = +listing[1].lstrip()+
```

If this is something simple, please forgive me.  I am but just starting out in the quest to conquer :)

Comment: It would help, if you show sample CSV and expected XML output.

Comment: Do you get an error?  A traceback?  An unexpected result?  It's unclear what your trouble actually is here.

Comment: My apologies for the vagueness - it ended up being a simple syntax issue:  Needed to drop the '+' signs from around listing[0] and listing[1] and it worked.  

No need to try to increment things along - for does that automagically.